# Google Drive API for Objective-C return some file not all

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-api-objc-client

I'm implementing Google Drive Api for my mac application using Google API Client for REST Library below,

```
- (void)fetchFileList {

_fileList = nil;
_fileListFetchError = nil;


GTLRDriveService *service = self.service;

GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList query];

// Because GTLRDrive_FileList is derived from GTLCollectionObject and the service
// property shouldFetchNextPages is enabled, this may do multiple fetches to
// retrieve all items in the file list.


query.fields = @"kind,nextPageToken,files(mimeType,id,kind,name,webViewLink,thumbnailLink,trashed)";



_fileListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                      completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket,
                                          GTLRDrive_FileList *fileList,
                                          NSError *callbackError) {
                          // Callback
                          _fileList = fileList;
                          _fileListFetchError = callbackError;
                          _fileListTicket = nil;



                          NSLog(@"%@", fileList);


                      }];
}
```

Here the return value

**GTLRDrive_FileList 0x6080002404e0: {kind:"drive#fileList" files:[5]}**

> There are 7 items on my drive but it returns only 5 items?

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with your *nextPageToken*. It returned only the result of a certain page, not all of them.

Check [this docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/queries#retrieving_multiple_pages_of_results):

> Sometimes a query may return a large number of results, which are
>   returned one page at a time. When a result object includes a
>   nextPageToken string, you can execute the query again; supply the
>   returned token as the pageToken property of the new query, fetching
>   the next set of results. You can repeat this until you reach the last
>   page, which will not inlude a nextPageToken string.

```
GTLServiceDrive *drive = ...;
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = search;
[drive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                              GTLDriveFileList *fileList,
                                              NSError *error) {
  if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Have results");
    // Iterate over fileList.files array
  } else {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
  }
}];
```

Try the Drive sample from the [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart#step_3_set_up_the_sample) on how to fetch Files properly. Here's a snippet:

```
/ Construct a query to get names and IDs of 10 files using the Google Drive API.
- (void)fetchFiles {
  self.output.text = @"Getting files...";
  GTLQueryDrive *query =
  [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
  query.pageSize = 10;
  query.fields = @"nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
  [self.service executeQuery:query
                    delegate:self
           didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

Comment: It returns 7 items correctly ONLY the first run of the application (Click Run) since boot!

Now, the second run and afterward returns   0 !!!!!

This give me an headache!!

Comment: noogui, I'm using the same code and notice the problem occurs ONLY after the first run! (Run -> Stop -> Run again)